# callback() or return callback()

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

It's possible I don't understand Node's event loop well enough.

Say I have a function `foo` which contains an asynchronous function `async_func`. Do I have

```
//1
function foo(callback) {
       //stuff here
       async_func(function() {
            //do something
            callback();
       });
//this eventually get executed
}
```

or

```
//2
function foo(callback) {
       //stuff here
       async_func(function() {
            //do something
            return callback();
       });
//never executed
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Actually, in your sample 2, `//never executed` will be execute every time. It's returning from the callback, not from the wrapping function.

Sometimes the caller actually expects some return value and the behavior can change based on that. Another common reason to see a return callback() is just a clear way of short circuiting the function you're in. For example.

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    something(function(err, data) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        // Only run if no error
    });
    // Always run
}
```

Even though the return value isn't being used, it's using return to ensure that execution doesn't continue past the error conditional. You could just as easily write it this way which has the same effect.

```
function doSomething(callback) {
    something(function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        // Only run if no error 
    });
    // Always run
}
```

Comment: @Timothy, good answer but the `_.find` is misleading and I would suggest you remove it. `_.find` is synchronous and does not take a callback. It takes an iterator function, uses it while processing, but then still returns a result synchronously. This example will just confuse people.

Comment: @TimothyStrimple would the callback itself continue to execute? in your first and second examples? -- i.e. does it go into web/node APIs and keep running?