# nodejs what is the difference between return callback() and just callback()

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I think this might actually answer another of my questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878325/nodejs-error-callback-was-already-called) if I can get this confirmed.

What is the difference between returning a callback and just calling a callback?

I have seen code doing either/or/both and trying to wrap my head around why and when to do which.

```
function test(x, y, callback){
    return callback(null, x);
    callback(null, x + y);
}

test(1, 2, function(err, results){
    if(!err){
        console.log('results:\n', results);
    } else {
        console.error('err:\n', err);
    }   
});
```

Edit: 
I think part of my questions resolves around my [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878325/nodejs-error-callback-was-already-called), where I would constantly get an error, callback already called.

I was trying to understand the conceptual difference between these two different ways to do in my mind the same thing. Not sure why I am getting voted down when I ask a question to better understand a concept I haven't grasped yet. Aren't we all here to expand on our knowledge of programming by asking questions of better programmers than ourselves?

Comment: I think you may have over-simplified, since `function test(x, y, callback) { return callback(null, x); }` would be a fairly unusual thing to have. So the answer to the question actually asked probably won't help you much with your real problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [callback() or return callback()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217589/callback-or-return-callback)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return callback();
//some more lines of code;
```

the comment section won't be executed in above but will be in the below

```
callback();
//some more lines of code;
```

Edit :

Of course returning will help the context calling async function get the value returned by callback but usually async function are not called to assign anything.

Also, you use this trick usually with an if block, something like this :

```
asyncFunction (params, callback) {
if(err) callback(err, null);
callback(err, result);
}
```

To avoid callback being called twice you do something like this :

```
asyncFunction (params, callback) {
if(err) return callback(err, null);
callback(err, result);
}
```

Comment: There are more side effects here

Comment: I have edited the answer. Is this what you are talking about, @mplungjan?

Comment: see my answer for a simpler explanation - not that yours is wrong

Answer (score 5):

1. callback(); // execute
2. return callback() // execute and pass whatever callback returns

So

```js
function test(x, y, callback){
    return callback(null, x);
    callback(null, x + y); // never executed
}




// 1st example: 

test(1, 2, function(err, results) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('results:\n', results);
  } else {
    console.error('err:\n', err);
  }
});

test(3, 4, function() {
  console.log("done")
}); // will alert done`

// 2nd example: 

console.log(test(5, 6, function() {
  return "done";
  // whatever here will not execute
})); // will alert done`
```

Comment: So both example 1 & 2 alert done?  The marked answer is something I can understand.

Comment: @KingAndrew The marked answer was not complete. Perhaps my updated answer helps?

Comment: Yes much better+1

Answer (score 1):

```
return callback(null, x);
```

does not return `callback`, but rather the result from calling the function. Whether or not this is a meaningful value depends on the implementation of `callback`.

If you simply call `callback` without returning the result, your function execution will continue as you do not return, and unless you return a value at a later point, `test` will return `undefined` in the end.

All in all, both approaches can make sense, however it heavily depends on your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

The only real question here is: do you want to have your `callback` dictate the return value of your outer method? If so, use `return callback(...)`; otherwise, just use `callback(...)`.